# Как изменить частоту дискретизации у аудио?

Tags: python, librosa

у меня следующая проблема - мне нужно из аудио 44.1КГц сделать 16КГц
я делал это следующим образом:

```
data, rate = librosa.load(path, sr=16000)
```

Есть ли какие то другие способы перевода / считывания с нужным битрейтом?

Comment: пересохрани файл через конвертор аудио

Answer (score 1):

Есть множество как методов (speex-1, speex-5, speex-10, soxr-lq, soxr-mq и др.), так и реализаций (`pydub set_frame_rate()`, `scipy.signal resample()` и др.), которые позволяют изменять частоту дискретизации аудио

При выставлении частоты дискретизации в функции библиотеки `Librosa` `Load(..., sr=)` используется встроенная в библиотеку функция `Resample()`, которая использует по умолчанию метод `soxr_hq`. Также при отдельном использовании функции `Resample()` можно выбрать метод дискретизации (soxr_vhq, soxr_hq, soxr_mq или soxr_lq), которые отличаются качеством выходного аудиосигнала. Использование `soxr_hq` более чем достаточно для любого уровня задач понижения семплрейта.